# How to handle mouse wheel events in the Pyxel game engine

Tags: events, mouse

I'm trying to handle mouse wheel input (aka scroll wheel) on a plain old mouse.

```python
if pyxel.btn(pyxel.MOUSE_WHEEL_Y):
    print(pyxel.mouse_wheel)
```

This never triggers.

The `pyxel.mouse_wheel` value holds small signed integers when I use the wheel while triggering another input e.g. keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

The *yet to be documented* `btnv` function must be used to test the occurrence of 'valued' events such as analog sticks and various wheels:

```python
if pyxel.btnv(pyxel.MOUSE_WHEEL_Y):
    print(pyxel.mouse_wheel)
```